# iOS 8 https proxy not working

Tags: proxy, man-in-the-middle

I use Cellist from the Mac App Store as a http/s proxy on my mac and it supposedly was possible to intercept https traffic via MITM attacks with it, but ever since iOS 8 there must have been a change to how iOS handles TLS traffic and now you only get an error in safari.

```
There was a problem communicating wit the secure web proxy server (HTTPS)
```

I have seen the same problem with other popular tools like Charles as well but no solution.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: This problem is common ..... There is not any solution to it yet, so you just have to wait ......

Comment: https://github.com/patr0nus/cellist-support/issues/28

Comment: You mean the problem is gone?